# Not found class in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

O model só dá NOT FOUND em um controller que gerencia Noticias.

> ERROR: Fatal error: Class 'App\Models\Site\NoticiaModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ManagerContent\App\Controllers\Site\HomeController.php on line 13

Segue link no pastebin para entender o problema:
http://pastebin.com/HkPjXL0j

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Site;

class NoticiaModel extends \ActiveRecord\Model {

    static $Table = 'noticia';
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Site;

use \App\Controllers\BaseController as Base;
use \App\Models\Site\NoticiaModel as Noticias;

class HomeController extends Base {

    public function index() {

        // List Noticias
        $Noticias = Noticias::all();
        dump($Noticias);

        $Dados = ['titulo' => 'Home'];
        $Template = $this->Twig->loadTemplate('Home.html');

        $Template->display($Dados);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse framework foi você quem criou?

Comment: Foi sim. Eh uma estrutura padrão de base que criei, onde só crio os controllers que preciso.

Comment: Isto está com cara de Laravel combinado com http://twig.sensiolabs.org, é isso?

Comment: Exato, Guilherme. Dentro do projeto, via composer chamo o Twig e o os helpers do Laravel. :)

Comment: Mas não entendo pq a Model de Noticia da not found no controller do Home, pra listar notícias. Já revi os path e ta tudo okay. :(

Comment: Então a sua afirmação ao @rray está errada jonniehenrique, ele perguntou se o framework foi você quem criou, mas isto é errado, na verdade você criou a aplicação que usa um framework existente chamado Laravel. Por favor da proxima vez poste as informações com clareza pois isto complica o entendimento ;)

Comment: Eu postei com clareza, Guilherme. Falei q criei uma estrutura base usando helpers do Laravel. A estrutura eh total independente de qualquer framework. :)

Answer (score 3):

Resolvido o problema!

```
composer update
```

O problema simplesmente no autoload dos diretorios Models que estava apontando para outra parte do projeto, fazendo com que não seja reconhecido nenhum model criado dentro do projeto! :)